# update login table field date and time in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

i have made login form from where when ever user sign In and that is successfully signed in .but at the time of login i need to update that user's date and time of sign in.
but i'am not able to update it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "I am not able to update it"? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Could you at least post your login controller. All you have to do is write a tiny insert line after a successful login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this....

```
if( $query->num_rows() )
                {

                     $data = array(
                    'lastloginD' => CURDATE(),
                    'lastloginT'  =>CURTIME(),

                    );
                    $this->db->where('id',$id_value);
                    $this->db->update('fit_1login', $data);

                    redirect('fit_formlogin');


                }
```

Comment: @shilpa what di you mean `lastloginD` and `lastloginT`?

Comment: lastloginDate and lastloginTime

Comment: i think here i need to add where id ="" so that it will only update a particular user id which is signing in

Comment: if answer is useful plz accept and vote up...thank you...if you got any problem comment..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

class Fit_logmodel extends CI_Model
{

```
 //get the username & password from tbl_usrs
 function get_user($usr, $pwd)

 {


        $this->db->where('regID', $usr);
        $this->db->where('loginCode',$pwd);
        $query = $this->db->get('fit_1login');




     if( $query->num_rows() )
                {

                     $data = array(
                    'lastloginD' => 'NOW()',
                    'lastloginT'  => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',

                    );
                    $this->db->replace('fit_1login', $data);

                    redirect('fit_formlogin');


                }
                  return false;
```

}

```
      //return $query->num_rows();
```

}?>

Comment: but this update query adding zero entry in my table with date 00:00:00 time00:00:00